# rails search a category for sub categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins, nested

http://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set

awesome nested set plugin and currently, if I choose a sub category as my category_id for an item, I can not search by its parent.

```
Category.parent
     Category.Child
```

I choose Category.child as the category that my item is in. So now my item has category_id of 4 stored in it.

If I go to a page in my rails application, lets say the Category page and I am on the Category.parent's page, I want to show products that have category_id's of all the descendants as well.

So ideally i want to have a find method that can take into account the descendants. You can get the descendants of a root by calling root.descendants (a built in plugin method).

How would I go about making it so I can query a find that gets the descendants of a root instead of what its doing now which is binging up nothing unless the product had a specific category_id of the Category.parent.

I hope I am being clear here. I either need to figure out a way to create a find method or named_scope that can query and return an array of objects that have id's corresponding tot he descendants of a root OR if I have any other options, what are they?

I thought about creating a field in my products table like parent_id which can keep track of the parent so i can then create two named scopes one finding the parent stuff and one finding the child stuff and chaining them.

I know I can create a named scope for each child and chain them together for multiple children but this seems a very tedious process and also, if you add more children, you would need to specify more named scopes.

```
//this is what i tried first
@category = Category.find(params[:id])
@child_products = @category.descendants.products

//this actually works but only for one
@child_products = @category.descendants.first.products
```

because a product belongs_to a Category and a Category has many products. However, the descendants function gives back an array of all the descendants. How do I filter through those and get the combined products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the named scope to your `Product` model, since that's what you're trying to display.

```
# product.rb    
named_scope :for_category_ids, lambda {|ids| {:conditions => {:category_id => ids}}}
```

Then in your controller:

```
@products = Product.for_category_ids(@category.descendants.map(&:id))
```

Comment: hey jdl does this work if the category has multiple sub categories?

Mysql::Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s): SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE (category_id = 4,5)  LIMIT 0, 4

is what i am getting back. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Yes, it should work for any list of ids. I missed a brace in the named_scope when I first posted this. Try again, and see if it works for you.

Comment: ah thanks jdl I appreciate this. I had changed the named_scope to named_scope :for_category_ids, lambda {|ids| {:conditions => ["category_id = ?", (ids)]} } which is why it failed. Thanks a lot.